# Simple WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I tried to write my First WCF service and here i have some problems,

First,I create a WCF Project,
Then i added Entity Model.
After that i added IEmpService.svc file.then i'm going to get a List of Customers.

I follow [THIS BLOG POST](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d13d20/creating-aspnet-mvc-app-with-wcf-service-docx/)

IEmpService

```
   [ServiceContract]
public interface IEmpService
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<Customer> GetAllCustomers();

}
```

EmpService

```
   public class EmpService : IEmpService
{
    public EmpDBEntities dbent = new EmpDBEntities(); // I can't create thisone inside GetAllCustomer method.

    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers
    { 
     //var x = from n in dbent.Customer select n; // This is what i need to get but in here this program not recognize `var` also.
     //return x.ToList<Customer>();
    }
}
```

Can anyope please tell me which point i'm missing ? or whythis problem happend? how to solve this ?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Could you be more specific on where you are having issues?

Comment: @jp2code In my EmpService file inside the GetAllCustomers method, the commented lines are not recognize

Comment: You are missing parentheses on `GetAllCustomers()`

Comment: I also was not the person who just downvoted this. I do not think downvotes are a helpful feature of this site.

Comment: What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: @jp2code exactly.because this is my first wcf service and it maybe a not well received question ,but it's not helpful me to downvote. :(

Comment: @jp2code .net framework 4.5

Comment: @JohnKoerner Yes.Correct.Silly mistake parenthasis missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still confused by your question, but I will attempt an answer.

Your **Customer** class needs to have a **DataContract** with **DataMembers** if you want to return it.

You probably saw this example:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Also, do not return **List**. Microsoft has List defined, but this is a web service - the rest of the world (apple, android, linux, php, etc) will not know how to interpret a List.

Instead, change your function's signature to an array of strings.

```
[OperationContract]
string[] GetAllCustomers();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what your question is, but did you define "Customer" as a DataContract?  If that's the object that your service returns, you need to define it so the client can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `public` keyword if you want to create this inside `GetAllCustomer` method. Like this:

```
public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    EmpDBEntities dbent = new EmpDBEntities();
    var x = from n in dbent.Students select n; 
    return x.ToList<Student>();
}
```